# Nativescript radListView do not show Item

Tags: angular, nativescript, radlistview

## **Overview**

Nativescript radListView does not show bind item from component on both  ios and android os. 
Action bar and usual ListView shows data but radlistview do not.
Console shows no error.
But I saw RadListView from next repository can work -> https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular

## **Environment**

My development environment is below.

os: macOS sierra 10.12.6 
node : v6.12.0 
npm : 3.10.10 
nativescript and others can be seen after, at package.json

## **Consideration**

I seems this problem is about these... 
but I can not refine.

1. angular directive
2. initializing an observable array

## **Code**

I implemented RadListView on angular like below just after 'tns create ui-test --ng'.

**Component**

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
    private _dataItems: ObservableArray<Item>;

    constructor() {
    }

    get dataItems(): ObservableArray<Item> {
        return this._dataItems;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._dataItems = new ObservableArray([
            { id: 1, name: "Ter Stegen", role: "Goalkeeper" },
            { id: 3, name: "Piqué", role: "Defender" },
            { id: 4, name: "I. Rakitic", role: "Midfielder" }
        ]);
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<ActionBar title="My App" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>

<GridLayout>
    <RadListView [items]="dataItems">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label class="nameLabel" text="text"></Label>
                <Label class="nameLabel" [text]="item.name"></Label>
                <Label class="descriptionLabel" [text]="item.role"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.uitest",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.3.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.0.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "5.0.0",
    "nativescript-fresco": "^3.0.2",
    "nativescript-intl": "^3.0.0",
    "nativescript-pro-ui": "3.3.0",
    "nativescript-unit-test-runner": "^0.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself.
A RadListView require a getter and an ObservableArray implementation, and correct html coding.
I didn't fill parameters like row.

But I don't understand how to use a radListView well.
Now I'm in trouble for a radListView layout with another GridLayout.

Comment: Not really, I'm having a similar issue, but from what I can tell so far, if you manually set a data array for `RadListView` to consume it will pick up that data nicely, no Observable needed.

Answer (score 5):

I did get your code and put in the home.component
After the tns create uitest --ng
then tns plugin add nativescript-ui-listview
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
tns build android
tns run android

It works if you don't forget to import this module in the home.module.ts :
NativeScriptUIListViewModule

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";

import { HomeRoutingModule } from "./home-routing.module";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    NativeScriptUIListViewModule
],
declarations: [
    HomeComponent
],
schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

with this item.model.ts

```
export class Item {
  id: number;
  name:string;
  role: string;
}
```

**Important**

In one another project, it didn't work until I add theses lines in the app.module.ts

```
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular/listview-directives";

@NgModule({
imports: [
    ...
    NativeScriptUIListViewModule
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `_dataItems` instead of `dataItems`? It looks like you've defined an itemsource and referenced it without the `_` in RadListView.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried your way, but I got same result.